# mysql script only reloads

Tags: php, mysql, sql

If I click submit it only refreshes the site. The connect.php is correct. But something has to be incorrect.

in.php

```
<form id="mathe1" action="script.php" method="post">
    <input name="nummer" type="number" value=""/><br><br>
    <label id="label"><p>Hausübung</p></label>
    <textarea name="hu" cols="60" rows="5"></textarea><br><br>
    <input name="Submit1" type="submit" value="Senden"/>
</from>
```

script.php:

```
<?php    
include('include/connect.php');

$nummer = $_POST['nummer'];
$hu = $_POST['hu'];
$db = "hu";

if (empty($nummer)) {
    header('Location:in.php');
}
if (empty($hu)) {
    header('Location:in.php');
}
else {
    $sql = "INSERT INTO $db VALUES ('$nummer','$hu')";
    $query = mysql_query($sql);
}
?>
```

Comment: FYI  your closing <form> tag has a typo  `</from>`

Answer (score 0):

It appears you have wrong defined if statement and location should be defined absolutely, so:

in include/connect.php

```
  $mysqli = new mysqli('sqlhost', 'user', 'password', 'db');
```

in scpipt.php

```
  $nummer = $_POST['nummer'];
  $hu = $_POST['hu'];
  $table = "hu";
  $url = "http://yourdevhost/in.php";

  if (empty($nummer) || empty($hu)) {
    header('Location: '.$url);
  } else {
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare('INSERT INTO ? VALUES (?, ?)');
    $stmt->bind_param('sss', $table, $nummer, $hu);
    $stmt->execute();
  }
```

Comment: ouh sorry i did this in my script. I only forgot it in the stackoverflow code.

Comment: and what about </from> vs. </form> it's only typo here or in your source to?

Comment: also a typo sorry

Comment: I updated your code. The right solution is to use mysqli and bind_param, which checks the data type of used variables. Just tried everything in my dev environment and worked perfectly fine.